# Trick to remember the difference between $\sqrt[b]{a^b}=a$ and $\log_a{a^b}=b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I always forget which operation on $a^b$ gives $a$ and which operation gives $b$.

The answer of course is that:

$\sqrt[b]{a^b}=a$ and $\log_a{a^b}=b$

Somehow I always confuse the two.

Question: how can I easily remember the difference between the two? Any mnemonic rules?

Comment: The inverse of $x^n=y$ is $x=\sqrt [n] y$.  That because the "opposite" of raising something to a specific power is to take a specific root.  The inverse of $b^x$ is take a specific base and raising it to a variable power.  The inverse of that is to take the base.  If you remember what the functions *are* and that they are inverses of basic ideas.... you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: @GambitSquared Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wanted to comment, but I don't have enough reputation...

Both results come straightforwardly from the definitions. If you have them clear in your mind, you shouldn't have this problem... Indeed, the square root is, in some domain (for example, in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$), the inverse function of the power. This means precisely that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ you have $\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a$.
As for the logarithm with base $a$, again with some care about the domain, it is the inverse function of the power with base $a$, so, again, you get precisely your result.

Also a numerical example could do the trick. Just think about $\sqrt[2]{a^2}$ (if you want, also give a numerical value to $a$, but choose it different from $b=2$; for examples, for $a=3$ you get the square root of 9, which is $a$). As for the logarithm, just think about the logarithm with base 10, which "counts" the number of zeroes of the powers of 10: $Log_{10}(10^b)=b$, because $10^b$ has $b$ zeroes.

Comment: It's a very nice answer, don't need to put that as a comment!

Answer (score 2):

As a memnonic rule, recall that we usually write

$$\sqrt[n]{x}=x^\frac1n$$

therefore

$$\sqrt[b]{a^b}=(a^b)^\frac1b=a^\frac b b =a^1 =a$$

For the $\log$ just keep in mind the definition

$$\log_a x=b \iff a^b=x$$

Comment: Add to that that $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$, and then, if our logarithm happens to be base $a$, we get $b\log_a(a)=b\cdot 1$.

Comment: @Arthur Nice observation!

Comment: Be carefully with the algebra $$\log(x^2)\ne 2\log(x)$$ in the general case.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes of course we are taking as usual $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$ but of course we need to be aware for the other particular case.